# Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made

Tags: wcf

While accessing the WCF service method , I received the following error
"There was no endpoint listening at

```
 http://ABC:1062/MyService.svc
```

that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."

The inner exception is

"Unable to connect to the remote server"

"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it "

Please help

Comment: What did you do to make sure there actually *is* a service listening at that address? From all we know, your computer is right. There is no service at the address you provided.

Comment: How is your service hosted?  Is the client using the same binding as the service?  Is the service up and running (can you get to the service page in a browser)?

Comment: Here is the solution..
Binding was changed , I just need to update the service reference and its done..!!